Calculating cheapest cylindrical tank
I've come across this problem in "Calculus for the Practical Man", in chapter 9, problem 4.

What are the most economical dimensions of an open cylindrical water
tank if the cost of the curved side per square foot is two-thirds the
cost of the bottom per square foot?

Since no volume is given, the question is asking for relative proportions.
Since it's an open tank the cost is the area of the bottom plus 2/3 the area of the "curved side".
$$C = \pi r^2 + \frac23( 2\pi rh )= \pi r^2 + \frac43\pi rh $$
$$\frac{dC}{dr} = 2\pi r + \frac43 \pi h = 2\pi\left(r + \frac23 h\right)$$
Setting the derivative to 0 for minimum:
$$r + \frac23 h = 0$$
$$r = -\frac23 h$$
That's the same solution as in the book, but what's tripping me up is the minus part. It makes no sense to just disregard it, and it also makes no sense to say that a cylinder's height is a different sign to it's radius. But what's really absurd is that it seems any solution to a similar question would end up with different signs for the height and radius because the cost would always be the sum of these two parts.

Hi! Please typeset your mathematics using MathJax. Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, $B = \pi r^2$ yields $B = \pi r^2$, and $\frac{dB}{dr} = 2\pi r$ yields $\frac{dB}{dr} = 2\pi r$.

I edited the equations so they are displayed nicely. Once it has been approved, please click the edit button to see how it has been done, so you can do it yourself next time :)

I've made some further edits, since it's somewhat unidiomatic to right $r^2\pi$ instead of $\pi r^2$, and it may confuse some readers (and similar instances elsewhere). I've also "uprighted" the fractions, to avoid ambiguity. ¶ In reference to the problem itself, note that the question does not specify a target volume. That suggests to me that perhaps the question is just asking for the optimal relative proportions, as opposed to specific dimensions. Can you say whether there's anything in the context around the question that confirms or denies that?

Thanks for the notation help, I'll use it in the future. Yes, the question is asking for relative proportions but those still shouldn't be of opposite sign.

For instance, your second line correctly indicates that cost is an increasing function of both radius and height. So trying to minimize cost absolutely, even under the constraint of physicality, would lead to zero radius and height.

Has no data been given about the volume of the cylinder? Is it constant?

@skugz: Ahh, if it's asking for relative proportions, then you'll want to imagine a target volume $V$. To obtain that target volume, you can make $r$ large (a wide base) but $h$ small (a squat cylinder), or you can make $r$ small (a narrow base) but $h$ large (a tall cylinder). Neither of those will be optimal in the limit. Can you figure out how to determine which relative proportions will minimize cost while maintaining a volume of $V$?

Yes, zero for both variables is an answer to the equation $r + \frac {2}{3} h = 0$ , but there should be more. More importantly, they can't be of opposite sign.

By the time I explain how to set this up properly, I'll have written an answer, so I'll do that. In the meantime, please add directly into your post the information that the question is asking for relative proportions.

@BrianTung , if we consider the volume constant, we are getting $r_{\text{min}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4V}{6π}}$, but OP has provided no data about the volume...so is this helping?

@Gwen: See both my answer and that of infinitezero; they're nearly identical (so I may delete mine shortly).

@BrianTung no need to delete it since we basically posted at the same time.

@infinitezero: Ordinarily, I would delete my answer because it was marginally later, on the principle of minimizing wasted space. The answers are more or less identical. However, I so like that we both had trivial errors that we both fixed seconds before the other one commented, so I'm going to leave mine up for now.

@infinitezero: I upvoted your answer. So someone must have come by and upvoted mine but not yours. How rude. :-P

@BrianTung well my answer was off by a factor of pi, yours by a factor of $9/4$. So yours was closer and thus more upvote-worthy ;)

Your maths are right but you aren't solving the right problem. You are computing the radius for the cheapest tank for a given height, not the radius for the cheapest tank for a given capacity. Negative radius produce negative lateral area, which has negative costs, so the cheapest tank for any given positive height has negative radius.

The critical aspect of this question is that it is asking for relative proportions. With that in mind, suppose that our target volume is $V$. (Its exact value will not matter for the relative proportions.) We know that
$$
V = \pi r^2h
$$
From this, we can obtain
$$
h = \frac{V}{\pi r^2}
$$
Now, let's use this in the cost function you correctly obtained:
\begin{align}
C & = \pi r^2 + \frac43 \pi rh \\
  & = \pi r^2 + \frac43 \pi r \frac{V}{\pi r^2} \\
  & = \pi r^2 + \frac{4V}{3r}
\end{align}
Differentiate this to get
$$
\frac{dC}{dr} = 2\pi r - \frac{4V}{3r^2}
$$
Equating this to zero gives us
$$
2\pi r = \frac{4V}{3r^2}
$$
$$
r^3 = \frac{2V}{3\pi}
$$
Then, dividing both sides of our height expression by $r$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{h}{r} & = \frac{V}{\pi r^3} = \frac{3\pi}{2V} \frac{V}{\pi} \\
            & = \frac32
\end{align}
as desired.

Hehe, now I was just about to mention the 2/3 but you fixed it :p

@infinitezero: Touché!

Ah, that makes sense.
So was my original post answering a question something like: "What are the relative proportions to minimize cost of any cylinder (even of variable volume)?", to which the answer is: "The one with zero volume.", and the only way to keep volume 0 while permitting the change of other variables is to have them change in opposite ways?

@skugz: No. Your original computation answers a question closer to "what radius minimizes the cost of a cylinder of constant height", with a secondary mistake of ignoring the $r \ge 0$ boundary condition. Plugging in the impossible radius you got would actually produce a negative cost, cheaper than a cylinder of 0 volume.

@user2357112: Ahh yes, I think I misunderstood what OP was saying.

Clearly most economical would be a cylinder with radius 0, since that would cost nothing. So let's assume we need to find the best economical option for a given volume $V$.
$$V = \pi r^2 h \Leftrightarrow h = \frac{V}{\pi r^2} \tag{1}$$
Putting that $h$ into your cost equation:
$$C(r) = \pi r^2 + \frac{4}{3}\pi r \frac{V}{\pi r^2} = \pi r^2 + \frac{4V}{3r}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C}{\mathrm{d}r} = 2\pi r - \frac{4V}{3r^2} \overset{!}{=}0$$
$$r^3 = \frac{2V}{3\pi}$$
We can now divide $(1)$ by $r$ to get a ratio of the two:
$$\frac{h}{r} = \frac{V}{\pi r^3} = \frac{V}{\pi} \frac{3\pi}{2V} = \frac{3}{2} $$
In other words, your cylinder should be $\frac{3}{2}$ times as high as its radius.

LOL I was going to come over here and point out the missing factor of $\pi$ but you fixed it.

This answer is for the OP, addressing their confusion about why $r=-\frac{2}{3}h$ minimizes the cost function.
Your cost function is $C=\pi r^2+2r\pi hk=\pi r(r+2hk)$ where I'm using $k$ to indicate some differential cost on height materials ($k=\frac{2}{3}$ in your problem). This is a quadratic, with roots $0$ and  $-2hk$, and the vertex of the parabola, midway between the roots, is $(-hk,-\pi h^2k^2)$.
Because the cost is a quadratic function monotonically rising from root zero as $r$ increases, a real cylinder with $r,h>0$ must have some actual cost that grows with its size, and the silly solution of not building a cylinder at all or the cylinder in the limit as $r \rightarrow 0$ are the "cheapest" solutions, costing nothing. But with the cost function, real life aside, theoretically, the base always has positive cost due to the $r^2$ term, but there is actually a window of negative radii between $(-2hk,0)$ where you earn money back for building the cylinder with negative radius. Beyond $r=-2hk$, the squared term in the base takes over and you're paying for the cylinder again.


$$C = \pi r^2 + \frac43\pi r\color\red h $$
$$\frac{dC}{dr} = 2\pi r + \frac43 \pi h $$

The variable $h$ is actually a function of $r$ (that is, depends on $r),$ and your mistake is here treating $\boldsymbol h$ as a constant.
Furthermore, to obtain the required solution requires assuming that neither $\boldsymbol r$ nor $\boldsymbol h$ is zero, as shown in the other answers.
